# I need to replace Grass blocks in super flat to red sand

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like to change all the grass block s in the world to red sand with command blocks I was having problems with /fill. I am just starting to get used to commands and such so simple as possible would be appreciated.

Comment: Note: `/fill` is limited to 32768 blocks.

Comment: Does it have to be done with commands, or would it be fine to generate a world that already has red sand instead of grass?

Answer (score 4):

This is impossible as of now. You can change only loaded chunks. Unloaded chunks can't be changed.

Comment: As the issue is solved @Tebbe2002, would you mind clicking the excepted answer button?

Answer (score -2):

When you create a flat world there are a little text and the place where it stands air chance it to red_sand.

Comment: I...think? this tries to answer the question?  But I'm finding it really hard to parse.

Comment: @Frank I don't think it does. This is about creating a new world whereas OP is asking about editing an existing one.